# How can I install pyrit, requested by linset?

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I was using linset and it asked me to install pyrit. I am on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Focal. I don't know how to install pyrit. This is what happens when I try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pyrit
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyrit
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pyrit` package [was last available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pyrit) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS at version 0.4.0. You can install by manual package download:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pyrit/pyrit_0.4.0-7.1build2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./pyrit_0.4.0-7.1build2_amd64.deb
```

Or if you need latest version 0.5.0 [from GitHub](https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit/releases) use commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-scapy libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libpcap0.8-dev python2-dev python-is-python2

cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://github.com/JPaulMora/Pyrit/archive/v0.5.0.tar.gz
tar -xf v0.5.0.tar.gz
cd Pyrit-0.5.0
sed -i "s/COMPILE_AESNI/NO_COMPILE_AESNI/" cpyrit/_cpyrit_cpu.c
python2 setup.py build
sudo python2 setup.py install
```

and then test it with `pyrit benchmark` or `pyrit benchmark_long`.